# Rotate array without packages

Tags: rotating

So I'm trying to rotate a basic array:

```
\begin{array}[b]{*{4}c}\\
& 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\end{array}
```

But for a particular reason I can't use any packages. (So graphicx, rotating, rotfloat, etc. cannot be used) Is there a way to rotate a box/array with just native latex?

Comment: Copy the package source code in, then proceed as usual.

Comment: `graphicx` is a _required_ part of LaTeX: an installation without it is fundamentally broken. Can you explain the requirements a bit more?

Comment: I need something that doesn't use "\usepackage" or any of its equivalents as I'm writing something that should be able to be copied/pasted into an arbitrary latex document no matter what they have imported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a rather current latex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
  \begin{array}[b]{*{4}c}\\
    & 2 & 3 & 4\\
   5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
  \end{array}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_rotate:Nn\mybox{90}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usebox\mybox

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "rather current latex"? Like would 2020 version be ok? Or is that not current enough?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you were mentioning it because you knew one of the commands were more recently introduced. I'll go ahead and test it out on different versions and see where it works. Thanks!